# controller can't return result in JSON object in ajax response

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have to call and fetch data from rest API with in every second. So I call the method with time 1 sec. As follows.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ getData1() }, 1000);
```

Following is my Javascript function which call the controller.

```
function getData1(){
    var url=CONTEXT_ROOT+"/login/getdashboarddata1";
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",  
        url: url, 
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);                    

            },
         error: function(e){
             //alert(e);
         }
        });
}
```

This is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getdashboarddata1", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public JSONObject @ResponseBody getDashboardData1() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, NullPointerException{ 

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/r_f22bc0ac1fe48bce/dataService/lastdata/";
        String user = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        System.out.println("user: "+user);
        JSONObject obj = null;
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

If I run the program then jsp does not shows any alert. but if I change the return type of in controller to String then it shows proper JSON string in ajax response.

i.e. `[{"sno":"3618","data":"01","datetime":"2017-04-05 12:33:26.266"}]`

If i carry this, then I am unable to get data from JSON string.

please tell me what is my issue. or is there any other way to do this.?

Comment: I didn't get what issue you are facing after changing return type of method as string? If you want to take value from reaponse, just use data.sno

Comment: if I return the JSON data as a string from controller to ajax response, then `alert(data);` it shows `[{"sno":"3618","data":"01","datetime":"2017-04-05 12:33:26.266"}]` Now if i am going to get particular data like `alert(data.sno);` then it shows undefine.

Comment: I have a doubt  on `contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",` with syntax issue. that is for double quotes or single quotes. Can you correct me If I wrong..

Comment: you have json array, try with data[0].sno

Comment: Where is the `users` var defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have json array

```
[{"sno":"3618","data":"01","datetime":"2017-04-05 12:33:26.266"}]
```

Then access it using index:

```
data[0].sno
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply return a String from `getDashboardData1()`

And then in AJAX success callback:

```
JSON.parse(data)[0]['sno'];
```

> please tell me what is my issue. or is there any other way to do
>   this.?

You can't access attributes of a `string` literal, it has to be a `json object`.